# Exclude files from directory file list with specific extension

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to exclude files which end with the ".done" extension in a case insensitive manner (no matter whether its .done, .DONE, .Done etc).

I am using this function:

```
 Dim filesFromDownloadFolder = Directory.GetFiles(_chorusPath & ReportPaths.Download).Where(Function(name) Not name.EndsWith(".done", True))
```

but after i got this error appear:

```
The string comparison type passed in is currently not supported.  Parameter name: comparisonType
```

i guess i should instead of true put StringCompariision.something but i am not sure which of available option in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to set the ignoreCase parameter to True, but the only overload providing this option also expects a third parameter. You are instead setting The ComparisonType parameter to True, hence your error. Try instead the following, which will set a StringComparison:

```
Dim filesFromDownloadFolder = Directory.GetFiles(_chorusPath & ReportPaths.Download).Where(Function(name) Not name.EndsWith(".done", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: i want to exclude those files

Comment: your way is to include those files i want to get all files except those ending with .done (case sensitive no matter if .done or .DONE or DoNe)

Comment: Please see my edit, this will use LINQ instead of returning two lists and comparing them.

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` just a suggestion

Comment: ok this seems to be working files which ends with no matter .done or .DONE or DoNe are not taken under consideration. Which option should i use if i would like case sensivitive within done word?

Comment: If you require case sensitivity, you can remove the second parameter entirely or use another comparison rule like `StringComparison.Ordinal`.

Answer (score -2):

you are try to filter the directory with a file extension, why are you using linq
use the native method it is fast too

[Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT**

Sorry for the wrong info i didn't Read the question completly, my mistake
but still it seems Getfiles is not the right solution, if the user using .NET 4 and above then user can use

[Directory.EnumerateFiles Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.100).aspx)
It is faster than the getfiles

Comment: both doind the same. If you say so show me how to use native method to exclude .done files (no case sensivity)

Comment: This will only get you files which _match_ an extension, and GetFiles in itself doesn't allow more complicated regular expressions. To use the GetFiles function without LINQ you would require calling it once to get all files, again to get all .done files, and then taking a diff off the two returned lists.